# Converter byte em imagem usando <img src>

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, image, img

Pra converter um byte que vem do banco sql em imagem no ListView eu faço assim:

```
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" CssClass="image1style" 
        ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ 
        Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("imagem1")) %>'/>
```

Gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa mas usando

```
        <img src= " " ...
```

Funcionou assim:

```
 <img runat="server" ID="Img1" src = '<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," 
  + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("imagem1")) %>'
```

Comment: O que é aquele `imagem1` dentro do `Eval`?

Comment: @jbueno é o campo da tabela que contem o array de bytes (imagem). Eu consegui resolver esse problema simplesmente substituindo o controle por <img e repetindo o restante.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você consiga usando um script :

Html

```
<img id="MinhaImagem" src="" />
```

Script

```
document.getElementById("MinhaImagem").src = "data:image/png;base64," + Bytes;
```

Comment: já tentei assim, não deu.

Comment: Dá algum erro ? 
Esta migrando um serviço em ASP.NET WebForms para html5 ?

Comment: não dá erro, simplesmente não ocorre o esperado, ou seja, o controle não exibe a imagem.